# API Call to validate a field before save, would this be done on a before_save or inside the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Preface:**

In my application I have a model named `Order`, which contains a third party `order_id` that I need to validate before saving. To verify the id is correct, I make an API call to their order verification endpoint.

**Question:**

Where exactly I should perform this verification in a rails app? My first logical choice was the controller:

```
  def create
    order_id = params[:joint_membership_application][:order_id]

    # API call to check order status, true = order ID is verified
    if @client.order_valid?(order_id)
      @membership_app = JointMembershipApplication.create!(membership_app_params)

    # ...
  end
```

But I'm always reading that business logic should live inside the models, not the controllers. Would it be bad practice to make an API call inside a `before_save` callback for the model? If I placed this logic in the model, I would need to instantiate an API client on save which seems a bit weird.

I may very well be overthinking this, but wanted to hear from people with rails experience on where exactly I should be performing this sort of verification. Thanks!

Comment: I would place it in the controller, and use Sidekiq to async perform the verification. Or put in after_commit(it will be tricky to track order_id changed? in after_commit) and use Sidekiq to async perform the verification. But it depends on your requirements. Does order_id will be changed in other ways? Do you need real-time verification?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @FeifeiXiong, I think I'll stick with keeping it in the controller. Feel free to answer the question with your first suggestion and I'll mark it as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would place it in the controller, and use Sidekiq to async perform the verification (moving the logic into a worker).